# Duplicate unique key error after rollback in mysql

Tags: mysql, transactions, unique-key

I have a table like this

```
mysql> describe seudonimos;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_seudonimo | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| seudonimo    | varchar(45)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Let's assume that it is empty so autoincrement is 0. For example:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO seudonimos (seudonimo) VALUES ('Agatha Christie');
ROLLBACK;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;
```

As far as I konw, the rollback does not affect the autoincrement. So if I insert a new value the autoincrement will be 2 instead of 1. But if I try to insert 'Agatha Christie' again, I have the following problem:

```
INSERT INTO seudonimos (seudonimo) VALUES ('Agatha Christie');

#1062 - Duplicate entry 'Agatha Christie' for key 'seudonimo'
```

That is not what I expected. I expected this:

```
+--------------+--------------------+
| id_seudonimo | seudonimo          |
+--------------+--------------------+
|            2 | Agatha Christie    |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

What's wrong?

Comment: you're not actually setting auto increment are you?  please show us your statements leading up to the error.

Comment: `> set autocommit=0;

> start transaction;

> INSERT INTO seudonimos (seudonimo) values ('Johnny');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

> SELECT * FROM seudonimos where seudonimo = 'Johnny';
+--------------+-----------+
| id_seudonimo | seudonimo |
+--------------+-----------+
|          840 | Johnny    |
+--------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

> rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.06 sec)

mysql> set autocommit=1;

> INSERT INTO seudonimos (seudonimo) values ('Johnny');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'Johnny' for key 'seudonimo'`

Comment: Here it is! "1 warning (0.06 sec)" - run "show warnings;", it probably help you understand wat is going on.

Comment: That's it! Here's the warning `| Warning | 1196 | Some non-transactional changed tables couldn't be rolled back |` Perhaps the problem is that I have some triggers :),that insert, update and delete the the data in a table called seudonimos_consulta that has engine=MyISAM after insert, update and delete data from table seudonimos (engine=InnoDB). What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You probably use MyISAM engine... Run `show create seudonimos;` and see.

Comment: No, I'm using InnoDB engine for 'seudonimos'.

Comment: @Mario: can you post the create table statement anyway?

Comment: `| seudonimos | CREATE TABLE \`seudonimos\` (
  \`id_seudonimo\` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  \`seudonimo\` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (\`id_seudonimo\`),
  UNIQUE KEY \`seudonimo\` (\`seudonimo\`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=838 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
`